# Obtain the sum of values according to the conditions selected from two other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

All functions I seem to look at i.e. IF, SUMIF/S and COUNTIF/S keep returning the number of cells that meet my conditions. What I want to obtain is one single total of select values within a column which meet conditions in one column and another condition in a second column.

For example I have total meters of sections of a pipeline in column A, in column B it specifies what ground type the pipeline crosses beneath (e.g. field, footpath, road). In column C I have the diameter of the pipe (200, 150, 65).

So say I want from column A a total meters of pipe that passes under a field and is 200 in diameter.

How would I achieve this using a formula in Excel?

Comment: Never mind i found a answer, cheers

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Sum-values-based-on-multiple-conditions-e610ae0f-4d27-480c-9119-eb644f1e847e?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA

Comment: Adding this as a comment as you said you've tried SUMIFS - but this should work:  '=SUMIFS(A1:A4,B1:B4,"Field",C1:C4,200)'.  It's summing A1:A4, checking B1:B4 for "Field" and C1:C4 for 200.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have already come across:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"field",C:C,200)
```